# GDI+ performance for pixel level rendering

Tags: c++, gdi+

I am doing some animation based on an algorithm that is supposed to render a scene at 800 x 600 resolution. It will essentially be redrawing each pixel for every "frame" at, hopefully, no less than 30 FPS.

Would this be possible?

I guess I would be drawing bitmaps.

Thanks

Comment: Try it and see? The question is quite vague and I doubt anyone will provide you with an universally valid answer.

Comment: I understand, I guess what I am looking for is benchmarks or something. I don't know if i could get more detailed than this :/

Comment: Are you asking if GDI+ can draw bitmaps at >= 30 GPS? The answer is obviously yes, but it's more dependent on your users' graphics hardware than the graphics subsystem you're using. It won't be a problem on today's hardware, but it might be a problem on older systems. Either way, GDI+ is not at fault. Hard to give a better answer than this without knowing more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest bitmap pixel format on most hardware is 32PArgb.  A 800x600 bitmap takes about 8.5 milliseconds on my laptop when drawn unscaled with Graphics::DrawImage().  It has decent graphics hardware.  This goes up to 12 msec for other pixel formats.

What you can't predict is how much time you'll burn rendering the scene.  That's going to set your true FPS limit.  Graphics libraries like DirectX and XNA store texture bitmaps in video memory to speed up the rendering, you won't get this from GDI+.

Comment: Wow even 12 msec is great. I should be able to hit 30 FPS easy :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us **how** you intend to draw the scene (using what method). If by "pixel level" rendering you mean calling `SetPixel()` method, you should take a look at things like http://supercomputingblog.com/graphics/using-lockbits-in-gdi/

Answer (score 0):

The push of modern hardware is way, way, way in excess of those demands.